# Why is my code producing an output of nan?

Tags: c++

My code is producing an output of `nan`.

I have looked around and I'm guessing it is as the equation is complicated from what I gather C++ doesn't recieve complicated equations too well.

But that doesnt seem right.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    int Backfill;
    double SlopeAngleOfWall, AngleOfInternalFriction, AngleOfFrictionSoilAndWall, BackfillSlope, CoefficientOfActivePressure;

    cout << "Retaining Wall Calculator \n";


    cout << "Enter the slope angle of the wall, this is measured from the horizontal plane, therefor will be 90 degrees if the retaining wall is vertical \n";
    cin >> SlopeAngleOfWall;
    cout << "Enter the angle of internal friction \n";
    cin >> AngleOfInternalFriction;
    cout << "Enter the angle of friction between the soil and the wall \n";
    cin >> AngleOfFrictionSoilAndWall;
    cout << "Enter the angle of the backfill slope \n";
    cin >> BackfillSlope;


    /* To make sin function work is is typed (angle*pi/180) */
    /* To make sin square work is is typesd (pow(sin (angle*pi/180), 2.0) */
    /* To add a square root sqrt is used */

    CoefficientOfActivePressure = (pow (sin ((SlopeAngleOfWall + AngleOfInternalFriction)*pi/180), 2.0))   /    ((pow (sin (SlopeAngleOfWall*pi/180), 2.0) * sin ((SlopeAngleOfWall * AngleOfFrictionSoilAndWall) * pi / 180)) *( 1 + sqrt( ( sin ((AngleOfInternalFriction + AngleOfFrictionSoilAndWall) * pi / 180) * sin ( (AngleOfInternalFriction - BackfillSlope) * pi / 180) / sin (  (SlopeAngleOfWall - AngleOfFrictionSoilAndWall) * pi / 180 ) * sin ( (SlopeAngleOfWall + BackfillSlope) * pi / 180)))));

    cout << "The coefficient of active pressure acting on the wall is" << CoefficientOfActivePressure <<"\n"
}
```

Comment: *"from what i gather c++ doesnt recieve complicated equations too well"* - Not sure why you would conclude that *a computer would be bad at math*.  As a debugging step, break apart the many operations of your equation into individual lines of code, storing their results in variables to be used in the subsequent operations.  When you do that, which operation first produces an unexpected result?

Comment: What are the inputs when `NaN` is produced as output?

Comment: i have just been typing random angles to see if it gives me a output

Comment: The equation is not valid for all combinations of input. See my answer below.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to implement Coulomb's Theory of Lateral earth pressure. The formula looks like this:

[image: Equation]

(From [http://www.soilmanagementindia.com](http://www.soilmanagementindia.com/lateral-earth-pressure/coulombs-theory/coulombs-theory-for-earth-pressure-soil/13949))

Assuming that your implementation is correct, the only way to get `NaN` as result is if the square-root argument is negative.

The bottom line is that the equation is not valid for all possible combinations of input, and for the wrong set of input an output of `NaN` is to be expected.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i am trying to do, as you posted this i have noticed a mistake however what do you mean by The bottom line is that the equation is not valid for all possible combinations of input, and for the wrong set of input an output of NaN is to be expected.?

Comment: That that there are combination of input angles that, when used as input to the equation, produces `NaN` output. Or like this: You cannot input random angles and always expect valid result.